# What are the design patterns which used in Struts 1.x framework?

Tags: design-patterns, struts

What are the design patterns which used in Struts 1.x framework?

Answer (score 2):

> ActionServlet --> Front Controller
>
> RequestProcessor & ActionMapping --> Application Controller
>
> ActionForm --> Context Object
>
> Action --> Command Pattern

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this book?

http://java.sun.com/blueprints/patterns/

This is all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Struts controller uses the Command Design Pattern,Action classes use Adapter Design Pattern and process() method of the RequestProcessor uses the Template Method Design Pattern.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is the main pattern behind struts development. JSPs are used for view and then there is controller (Front controller Pattern) and then there is model.

The Actions are based on command pattern.

Struts uses ValueObject pattern also as we normally encapsulate all the data in an object and then pass it to JSPs.

There are many more patterns in struts.

Comment: Could you please tell us what are they and where are they used ?